# web application-file upload

Tags: file-upload

I am developing an web application. I am using file upload control to browse files. i have  xls file in C:\Mailid.xls path. When i use FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName command i was get the full path(C:\Mailid.xls).

Today I installed IE 8 After the installation I unable to get the full path of the file what could be the problem Event I uninstalled IE 8. Currently I am using IE 7.

how can i get the fullpath(C:\Mailid.xls) in my project.

Regards
Dhanraj.S

Comment: -1 for a pitifully chosen title to this question!

Comment: @Josh Stodola: So help to a new user with the question title instead to down vote his first question!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 
    System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(  ...  )

Comment: ya i tried below mentioned.

FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName).ToString();
Convert.ToString(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));